# Insert automatically generated primary key into another table when inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following stored procedure I am accessing through an ODBC connection.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddTransactions]
    @Transactions dbo.TransactionData READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Transactions (CustomerId, EmployeeId, VehicleId, ProductId, LocationId,
        Number, [Site], [Authorization], [TimeStamp], Odometer, PumpNumber,
        Quantity, UnitPrice, UnitDiscount, TotalAmount, Code)
    SELECT CustomerId, EmployeeId, VehicleId, ProductId, LocationId,
        Number, [Site], [Authorization], [TimeStamp], Odometer, PumpNumber,
        Quantity, UnitPrice, UnitDiscount, TotalAmount, Code
    FROM @Transactions
END
```

I think this is right. What I would like to do is insert the value for the `Transactions.Id` column (an identity column created by SQL Server) into another table (a table that has only one foreign key column).

I'm familiar with `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, but the `@Transactions` argument can have up to 25 rows and I'd like to insert the ID from each of those inserted rows. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

There should be nothing stopping you from doing another insert inside your current procedure, assuming you can get a hold of the last inserted ID:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddTransactions]
    @Transactions dbo.TransactionData READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Transactions (CustomerId, EmployeeId, VehicleId, ProductId, LocationId,
        Number, [Site], [Authorization], [TimeStamp], Odometer, PumpNumber,
        Quantity, UnitPrice, UnitDiscount, TotalAmount, Code)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
    SELECT CustomerId, EmployeeId, VehicleId, ProductId, LocationId,
        Number, [Site], [Authorization], [TimeStamp], Odometer, PumpNumber,
        Quantity, UnitPrice, UnitDiscount, TotalAmount, Code
    FROM @Transactions

    INSERT INTO SomeOtherTable(Id)
    SELECT ID FROM INSERTED
END
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain this a little? What does `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID` do? Where is it output to? Also, I had something similar, minus the last two lines, and the stored procedure was returning the rows from the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: This would output the value of the identity column generated during your first (current) insert into the virtual `INSERTED` table, which is a one rows dummy table which can hold things.  Then, in the following insert, we use insert that auto generated ID into another table.

Comment: So, if I'm inserting 25 rows, it doesn't sound like it would insert the IDs from all 25 of them.

Comment: @JonathanWood Yes, I believe you are right.  So, you might have to use a cursor to do the inserts one record at a time.

Comment: The `output` clause will capture all 25 new id's but you have to specify the temp table (or table var) to put them into. When in doubt check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @DaleBurrell Could you edit my answer and I would be happy to bestow up votes upon you?